# How to add method to base class?

Tags: python, class, parent-child

I want to add `__add__` and `__radd__` to the python base class `set`.

The code can be as simple as

```
def __add__(self, other) :
    assert isinstance(other, set), \
        "perhaps additional type checking or argument validation can go here but" + \
        " strictly only defined for pure python sets"
    return set( list(self) + list(other) )

def __radd__(self, other) :
    assert isinstance(other, set), \
        "perhaps additional type checking or argument validation can go here but" + \
        " strictly only defined for pure sets"
    return set( list(other) + list(self) )
```

What is the pythonic implementation of this and how can I extend the base class without creating my own `MySet` class that takes `set` as a parent class? Can I just use `set.__add__ = some_function_I_defined`?

Comment: What base class? Have you created the base class yourself?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add this behaviour to all existing `set()` instances? Otherwise it would really be simpler to create a subclass.

Comment: In general, yes, you can just assign a function to a new class attribute, but you cannot add new class attributes to built-in classes like `set`.

Comment: This is pretty non-standard, though. While *multisets* support distinct union and addition operations, the two operations are equivalent for sets. Just use `|` and `|=`, instead of making future readers of your code wonder why you *aren't*.

Comment: It's a bad idea to try to add methods to any kind of builtin or library class.  Instead, create a subclass and add them to that.

Comment: (That is, if you *could* modify `set`, you could just write `set.__add__ = set.__or__` and `set.__radd__ = set.__ror__`, instead of defining new, equivalent functions.)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do imho is subclass the built-in `set` class.
In Python (contrary to e.g. Ruby or JavaScript) monkey-patching a built-in is not allowed.

So e.g. trying to add a non-existent method:

```py
x = [1,2,3]
x.my_new_method_added_in_runtime = lambda: "whatever"
```

is not going to work, you'd get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'my_new_method_added_in_runtime'`

You cannot also modify the existing methods of objects instantiated using those built-ins:

```py
x = [1,2,3]
x.sort = lambda: "returning some string instead of sorting..."
```

will result in `AttributeError: 'list' object attribute 'sort' is read-only`

And

```py
list.append = None
# OR
del list.append
```

will result in:
`TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'`

All of the above is true for `set` as well an so on.

You could try to look for some libraries to achieve that e.g. https://pypi.org/project/forbiddenfruit/0.1.0/, but it's **strongly** discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

@chepner correctly answered my question without realizing it. I was trying to reimplement already existing functionality since I was not familiar with python sets.

The act of joining two sets, 'taking their union' is implemented with the python `__or__` and `__ior__` methods. The operation I needed specifically was `|` and `|=`.

In principle we should be able to set operations as chepner suggested with `set.__add__ = set.__or__`, but as chepner points out this results in an error:

```
TypeError: cannot set '__add__' attribute of immutable type 'set'
```

Thank you all.